# SQL Server on M1 based Mac

Tags: sql-server, docker, apple-m1

I am trying to install SQL Server on M1 based Mac with Docker.

https://debugsolutions.wordpress.com/2021/03/17/using-sql-server-on-m1-based-mac-with-docker/

Made it all the way to end of step 5, but my container won't connect. I am getting:

> 1/08/02 01:31:47 [launchpadd] INFO: Launchpadd is connecting to mssql on localhost:1431
>
> 2021/08/02 01:31:47 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to connect to SQL because: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1431: connect: connection refused, will reattempt connection.
>
> 2021/08/02 01:31:48 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to connect to SQL because: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1431: connect: connection refused, will reattempt connection.
>
> 2021/08/02 01:31:49 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to connect to SQL because: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1431: connect: connection refused, will reattempt connection.
>
> 2021/08/02 01:32:41 [launchpadd] INFO: Extensibility Log Header:
>
> 2021/08/02 01:32:41 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to load /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf ini file with error open /var/opt/mssql/mssql.conf: no such file or directory
>
> 2021/08/02 01:32:41 [launchpadd] INFO: DataDirectories = /bin:/etc:/lib:/lib32:/lib64:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/include:/usr/lib:/usr/lib32:/usr/lib64:/usr/libexec/gcc:/usr/sbin:/usr/share:/var/lib:/opt/microsoft:/opt/mssql-extensibility:/opt/mssql/mlservices:/opt/mssql/lib/zulu-jre-11:/opt/mssql-tools
>
> 2021/08/02 01:32:41 Drop permitted effective capabilities.
>
> 2021/08/02 01:32:41 [launchpadd] INFO: Polybase remote hadoop bridge disabled
>
> 2021/08/02 01:32:41 [launchpadd] INFO: Launchpadd is connecting to mssql on localhost:1431
>
> 2021/08/02 01:32:41 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to connect to SQL because: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1431: connect: connection refused, will reattempt connection.
>
> 2021/08/02 01:32:42 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to connect to SQL because: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1431: connect: connection refused, will reattempt connection.
>
> 2021/08/02 01:32:43 [launchpadd] WARNING: Failed to connect to SQL because: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:1431: connect: connection refused, will reattempt connection.

How can I fix this?

The command I ran at end of step 5:

```
docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e ‘ACCEPT_EULA=1’ 
    -e ‘MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password.1’ -p 1433:1433 --name azuresqledge 
    -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

Comment: If you're publishing port 1433 why is Launchpadd trying to connect on 1431?

Comment: In my case the issue went away by updating the podman GUI to just use 1 CPU on version v4.9.3

Answer (score 10):

` replace ' in docker command

```sh
$ docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -e 'ACCEPT_EULA=1' -e 'MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=Password.1' -p 1433:1433 --name azuresqledge -d mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party but if you don't want to resort to using the cutdown Edge edition I found away to get SQL Server Linux going using an open source tool called Lima and Rosetta as the VM: https://dev.to/srburnham/forget-azure-sql-edge-on-a-m1-mac-run-full-blown-sql-server-linux-instead-a-how-to-6d2